# How to view non-minified source files of node_modules declared in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

Here's an example, given a dependency and it's types:

```
npm i --save leaflet
npm i --save-dev @types/leaflet
```

When building angular (angular-cli 1.0, ng 4.0)

```
ng build
```

Looking in Chrome tools in `./~/leaflet/dist`

`leaflet.js` is the minified version of the library.

Is there a way to use the non-minified version in order to step into the code?

I tried adding that parameter but made no diff.

```
ng build --sourcemap
```

Comment: how are you including leafletjs i your project? in the scripts section of angular-cli file? ts import ?

Comment: @ahmed @types/leaflet puts the library in the global space...no need for any import

Comment: this might be new in angular cli 1.0.0 but installing any library by default does not mean it gets served as part of the app, nor does it make it to index.html. In any case, angular cli would add it to "scripts" section of the angular cli folder if it did it automatically.

you might want to try to include it explicitly in "scripts" and use --sourcemap or add it to index.html via a small script.

Comment: @ahmed musallam. yes i think you are right. it felt "new" after we went to 1.0.0 / ng 4.0. Theres a known issue with it